# Converting value to key from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a txt file with the following text:

```
water=45 
melon=8 
apple=35 
pineapple=67 
I=43 
to=90 
eat=12 
tastes=100 
sweet=21 
it=80 
watermelon=98 
want=70
```

and I have another file with the following text:

```
I want to eat watermelon
it tastes sweet pineapple
```

I want to output into:

```
I want to eat watermelon = 43,70,90,12,98
it tastes sweet pineapple = 80,100,21,67
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import nltk 
f = open(r'C:\folder\dic\file.txt','r')
answer = {}
for line in f:
     k, v = line.strip().split('=')
     answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()

f.close()

print answer.values()

h = open(r'C:\folder\dic\file2.txt','r')
raw=h.read()
tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)


for line in text:
    word = line
    for value in answer.values():
        if value == word:
            word=answer[keys]
        else:
            word="not found"

 print word
```

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: `[answer[c] for c in 'adfac']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code.

```
import re
f = open(r'C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop\val.txt','r')
val_dict = {}
for line in f:
     k, v = line.strip().split('=')
     val_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
f.close()

print val_dict

h = open(r'C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop\str_txt.txt','r')
str_list = []
for line in h:
     str_list.append(str(line).strip())

print str_list

tmp_str = ''
for val in str_list:
    tmp_str = val 
    for k in val_dict.keys():
            if k in val:
                replace_str = str(val_dict[k]).strip() + ","
                tmp_str= re.sub(r'\b{0}\b'.format(k),replace_str,tmp_str,flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    tmp_str = tmp_str.strip(",")
    print val, " = ", tmp_str
    tmp_str = ''
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.py
{'apple': '35', 'I': '43', 'sweet': '21', 'it': '80', 'water': '45', 'to': '90',
 'taste': '100', 'watermelon': '98', 'want': '70', 'pineapple': '67', 'melon': '
8', 'eat': '12'}
['I want to eat watermelon', 'it taste sweet pineapple']
I want to eat watermelon  =  43, 70, 90, 12, 98
it taste sweet pineapple  =  80, 100, 21, 67
```

Comment: Thank Dinesh it work, but there is a problem if the number 2 digits for example a =23 b=56 c =21, the result will be separated by commas.2,3,5,6,2,1.

Comment: @RiskaNanda - Please check the edited code now. Earlier I was replacing 'a' with 1, 'z' with '26' etc and then split and join string using comma ','. Thats why '26' is getting converted to '2,6'. Now I am going to replace 'a' with '1,'  'z' with '26,' etc. and then just removing ","  from end.

Comment: I tried for another case, data for  val_dict : `water=45
melon=8
apple=35
pineapple=67
I=43
to=90
eat=12
taste=100
sweet=21
it=80
watermelon=98
want=70`

and data for str_list : `I want to eat watermelon
it tastes sweet pineapple`
I got the results : `i want to eat watermelon  =  43, 70, 90, 12, 45,8
it tastes sweet pineapple  =  43,t 100,s 21, p43,ne35`
whether it can be in accordance with the word ?

Comment: Can you please tell me what us exact requirement? In first case you want to replace the characters by there number in comma separated format. Now you want replace the word with there number but no comma in between. These are two different things which can be achieved using different piece of code.

Comment: I want to create a file that contains the data dictionary in which contain hundreds of words along with an index number manually, then I have an other file that contains hundreds of phrases so I want convert words in the sentence to be in keeping with the Indexing data dictionary is created, if the in the sentence are the same word in the dictionary then the word will be converted into a number contained in the data dictionary and was separated by commas.

Comment: the source code above to work properly just there was a bit of a problem when there is a word such as pineapple was not the convert its entirety but only half, for example, there are two words in the dictionary
`apple = 1`
`pineapple = 3`
if on the other file contained the words pineapple then the result becomes `pine1` and the output is wrong, it should be converted into 3. I want the word to be compared as a whole.
I changed the part `if k == val:` but it did not work.

Comment: @RiskaNanda -  Please check the edited code. Since now we have find words (not characters), we have to use re (regex) module to match exact word (word can be present anywhere in line) and substitute with its code.